# Does Kotlin Coroutine Flow apis have bridge tools like Rx Subject?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

1. `Channel()`, `BroadcastChannel()` are similar to Rx `Subject`s. `Channel` have both sending and receiving methods makes it like a bridge or proxy, what are the equivalent method in newer `Flow` apis?
2. Lots of `Channel` functions are deprecated, should we avoid `Channel` completely from now on? Or `Channel` is same important to `Flow` for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now `Flow` doesn't support the same functionality as Rx `Subject`, because it represents a *cold* stream of data (i.e. you should not be able to post values to flow from outside the flow's builder. 
The closest analogue to Rx `Subject` is `BroadcastChannel`, because it supports multiple receivers (whereas `Channel` allows to have only one receiver). 
Most of the `Channel` stream methods, like `map`, `flatMap` and others were deprecated in favor of `Flow` stream methods. But instead you have an ability to represent your `Channel` as `Flow` using `BroadcastChannel#asFlow()` and `Channel#consumeAsFlow()` methods.

Comment: So the `Channel` have not completely abandoned yet, only its operators are deprecated, builder methods of `Channel` and `Channel` itself are still available in future? All I need is transforming `Channel` to `Flow` to continue using operators like `map`?

Comment: Exactly! In fact, I don't think the `Channel` class itself is going to be deprecated in the foreseeable future, because they are used to conduct inner communication between `Flow`s. For example, try looking inside some of `Flow` methods, like `debounce`, and you'll see that channels are used there internally. `produce` method there creates a separate coroutine which collects data from the outer `Flow`, which in its turn is used later to carry out `debounce` logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed `Channel` are used among `Flow` methods logic as well. Some moments I thought it was such a bad thing because almost all of its methods were deprecated suddenly...